# Converting MP4 to PAL DVD

Tags: dvd, encoding, open-source

I have a dozen or so mp4 files I downloaded from youtube. I would like to put these onto a DVD for a relative (He only has a DVD player, no PC or USB slot on tv)

I think DVD's have two folders audio_ts and video_ts. Can anyone point me to, or provide a workflow to convert the mp4 files to pal dvd's.

I will be using ffmpeg on a MBP OSX 10.10.5

I don't wont to lose any quality at all if possible. I have used ffprobe to get details on the mp4's, output is below. I have read some examples on converting the mp4's and outputting to a VOB file, but it doesn't mention anything about the audio and I'm at a loss with what quality will be be like.

Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'movie.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2015-10-18 17:44:18
  Duration: 01:29:29.38, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1936 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1741 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 191 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-10-18 17:45:35
      handler_name    : IsoMedia File Produced by Google, 5-11-2011

I'd also appreciate a breakdown of ffprobe output, I'm confused that stream #0:0 video reports h264 and avc1 ? I thought these are two different types of video codec?

Many thanks.

Comment: I have provided an app as well as this advice. All DVD formats are MP2 or MPEG-2 with PCM or AC3 audio.

Answer (score 1):

Try this open source software called "[Burn](http://burn-osx.sourceforge.net/Pages/English/home.html)". I have used it. It has many options for DVD burning.